# Setup gradle on existing project structure

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I have a java project with the following existing code structure:

```
src
 |- package1
    |- package2
    |- package3
    |- package4
    |- tests
```

As you can see above the package containing the tests (`tests`) is inside one of the package in the `src` directory.

I know that gradle requires src code to be under `src/main/java/` and tests to be under `src/test/java`. I want to setup gradle on this project but do not want to change my existing structure that I shown above.

Is there some way I can use my existing project structure with gradle?

any help appreciatated... thanks

Comment: There probably is, but it's just asking for trouble. Tools and developers expect the standard structure. Just use it. Moving 3 directories is really not a complex task.

Comment: @JB_Nizet: Moving 3 directories may be a _political_ task, which is inherently complex, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully this matches the request, but [here](https://github.com/codetojoy/easter_eggs_for_gradle/tree/master/egg_StackOverflow_51685286) is an example. Given:

```
src/net/codetojoy/Foo.java
src/net/codetojoy/service/FooService.java
src/net/codetojoy/tests/FooServiceTestCase.java
```

We can configure `sourceSets` for Gradle like so:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir 'src'
            exclude 'net/codetojoy/tests/*'
        }
    }
}

sourceSets.test.java.srcDir 'src/net/codetojoy/tests'
```

Comment: Im using intellij... On the `FooServiceTestCase.java` file, I am getting an error on the package line saying `Package name 'net.codetojoy.tests' does not correspond to the file path` ??

Comment: I would try my example on the command-line, then your code on the command-line, and then finally IntelliJ. Your question didn't mention IntelliJ so either that is a separate Q or you should perhaps update the original.

Comment: you are right - i have accepted your answer and opened a new question for intellij